# Glossaries package: inline and long glossary

Tags: glossaries

I've got a problem to switch back to the standard glossary style with the starred chapter after using an inline glossary.
Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[nonumberlist=true]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-inline}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newacronym{LED}{LED}{light emitting diode}
\newglossary*{Footnote}{}
\newacronym[type=Footnote]{FET}{FET}{field effect transistor}
\newacronym[type=Footnote]{OFET}{OFET}{organic field effect transistor}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\glsaddall %print all acronyms, whether used in text or not
\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{\textbf{#1}: } %as suggested in manual, page 198

\begin{document}
\gls{LED}, \gls{FET}, \gls{OFET}\\
This is a text with a footnote\footnote{\printnoidxglossary[type=Footnote,style=inline,title={Abbreviations used}]}

%\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}{\chapter}
%\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}{\chapter*}
\printnoidxglossary[nopostdot, type=main, style=long]
\end{document}
```

What I want is that the main glossary is in an unnumbered chapter, after using the Footnote glossary in the footnote.

I've tried `\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}{\chapter}`, which gives the chapter, but with the number. `\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}{\chapter*}` is compilable, but gives very strange output.

Trying to define an own inline style and changing glossarysection in there gives an error (Illegal parameter number in definition of \@glsstyle@myinline):

```
\newglossarystyle{myinline}{%
    \glossarystyle{inline}% 
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{\textbf{#1}: }%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to double the `#` parameter character when redefining commands inside `\newglossarystyle`. Like this:

```
\newglossarystyle{myinline}{%
  \glossarystyle{inline}% 
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{\textbf{##1}: }%
}
```

or using the newer `\setglossarystyle`:

```
\newglossarystyle{myinline}{%
  \setglossarystyle{inline}% 
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{\textbf{##1}: }%
}
```

(If you get an undefined control sequence error for `\setglossarystyle`, then your version of `glossaries` is very old and could do with being updated.) Note that the first parameter of `\glossarysection` is the title used in the table of contents. That happens to be the same as the actual title for your document, but syntactically I think it would be better to do:

```
\newglossarystyle{myinline}{%
  \setglossarystyle{inline}% 
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{\textbf{##2}: }%
}
```